# How would you replicate this Java public interface in Swift?

Tags: java, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to replicate an example Java public interface in Swift.  Here's what I have come up with.

Here is an example Java public interface:

```
public interface TestInterface {
     public static int MSG_1         = 0x11; 
     public static int MSG_2         = 0x22; 
     public static int MSG_3         = 0x33;

     public int getMessageType();
}
```

Then in a new class it will implement the TestInterface, for example:

```
 import com.myTestApp.TestInterface;

 public class msg1Type implements TestInterface {
       public int getMessageType() {
            return MSG_1;
       }
 }
```

In Swift I've done the following -- added a file called, TestInterface.swif:

```
import Foundation

    class TestInterface {
         let  MSG_1                    :Int = 0x11
         let  MSG_2                    :Int = 0x22
         let  MSG_3                    :Int = 0x33

         let getMessageType((void)->Int)
    }
```

Then in the class that implements TestInterface the getMessageType() function like:

```
import Foundation

class msg1Type : TestInterface {

        func getMessageType() -> Int {
            return MSG_1;
        }
}
```

What is the best way to approach this experiment?

Comment: Your code appears to reflect a poor understanding of fundamental Swift language concepts, including protocols, initializers, and even function signatures. Someone on SO may provide the right answer, but I would strongly encourage you to read Apple's official Swift book, and save yourself a lot of unnecessary trial and error.

Comment: @Matt - thanks, will spend some time actually reading than brute force attempting to learn SWIFT.   I like to use examples from other languages and then porting so I can learn differences between the two.  Perhaps not the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can see what your trying to do.

--> It's kinda like your looking for Abstract Classes (like in C++ for example) but there's some confusion between whether to use something else such as 'Protocols' *(as opposed to Java's 'Interface')*.

Instead...

**I suggest a slightly simpler solution:** 
Create a Class with a Default Method that you then Override later in a Sub-Class

First create the Super-Class with your Message Constants and Default Method

```
class TestInterface 
{
    let MSG_1:Byte = 0x11;
    let MSG_2:Byte = 0x22;
    let MSG_3:Byte = 0x33;

    func getMessageType () -> Byte 
    {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Then you can Extend the Super-Class and Override the MessageType Method

```
class SecondInterface : TestInterface 
{
    override func getMessageType () -> Byte
    {
        return MSG_2
    }
}
```

*(personally I think it's good practice to do cross-language experiments)*

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

```
enum MessageType: Int {
    case MSG_1 = 0x11,
    case MSG_2 = 0x22,
    case MSG_3 = 0x33 
}

protocol TestProtocol {
     func getMessageType() -> MessageType
}
```

Which could be implemented like this:

```
class Msg1Type: TestProtocol {
    func getMessageType() -> MessageType {
        return MSG_1
    }
}
```

Do not try to blindly convert concepts from Java to other languages, try to learn Swift from scratch if possible,

Answer (score 0):

I completely concur with matt.

```
class TestInterface  {

    let  MSG_1 :Int = 0x11
    let  MSG_2 :Int = 0x22
    let  MSG_3 :Int = 0x33

    func getMessageType () ->Int {
        return MSG_1
    }
}
```